# Translating Swift Into English

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to teach myself to code in Swift but I'm having a difficult time translating what I'm reading into something that resembles English. Here's an example:

```
func createAdder(numberToAdd: Int) -> (Int) -> Int
{
    func adder(number: Int) -> Int
    {
        return numberToAdd + number
    }
    return adder
}

var addTwo = createAdder(2)
addTwo(4)
```

How do I read that first line of code and can you explain how this function is executed?

Answer (score 3):

`createAdder` is a function that returns a function. The placement of the parentheses is a little off-putting - it makes more sense like this:

```
func createAdder(numberToAdd: Int) -> (Int -> Int)
```

So it returns a function of type `Int -> Int`. What does that mean? Take a look at this function:

```
func addTwo(n: Int) -> Int {
  return n + 2
}
```

That function takes an integer - `n` - and returns another integer. So the type of the function is:

```
Int -> Int
```

In this case, this function just adds two to whatever it was given. But say you wanted to generalise (it doesn't make much sense in this contrived example, but this kind of thing is very powerful in other scenarios). Say you wanted to have a bunch of functions, each of them adding a number to a number they were given. To do *that*, you'd need to write something like what you've written in your example:

```
func createAdder(numberToAdd: Int) -> (Int) -> Int
{
  func adder(number: Int) -> Int
  {
    return numberToAdd + number
  }
  return adder
}
```

The `createAdder` function takes a number, and then defines a new function - `adder` - which it returns.

The final bit that might be confusing is the line

```
var addTwo = createAdder(2)
```

Usually, you define functions with the word `func`. However, that's just syntax. Functions are variables just like every other type in Swift, and they can be treated as such. That's why you're able to return a function, and that's why you're able to assign it using `var`.

So what does it do? Well, if you call `createAdder(2)`, what you get back is equivalent to

```
func addTwo(n: Int) -> Int {
  return n + 2
}
```

If you did something like:

```
var addThree = createAdder(3)
```

It would be equivalent to:

```
func addThree(n: Int) -> Int {
  return n + 3
}
```

And in both cases, you'd use them just like normal functions:

```
addThree(1) // returns 4
```

So I said the example was a little contrived - and it is - so where would this kind of thing be useful? In general, functions that either take or return functions are called "higher-order" functions. They're *massively* useful, and if you go down the functional programming route they can get very powerful and a bit philosophical pretty quickly. Keeping it grounded, the first place most people come across them in Swift is with the function `.map()`. `map()` is a higher-order function - it takes a function as its parameter. However, it also takes something else - in this example, it's going to be an array. What it does is apply the function it's given to every element of the array. So, let's use the `createAdder()` to give us a function that adds 1 to a number:

```
let addOne = createAdder(1)
```

Right, then let's get an array of other numbers:

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then, let's put it all together with `map`:

```
let mapped = nums.map(addOne) // [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As you can see, that's a pretty powerful way to process and manage arrays. There's a whole host of functions like this - `filter()`, `flatMap()`, `reduce()` - and they all rely on this concept.

Answer (score 1):

It reads: declare a function named "createAdder" that takes an Int as an argument, this function *returns a function* which itself takes an Int as an argument; and this function itself, what is returned from "createAdder", returns an Int.

```
-> (Int) -> Int
```

means "returns a function -taking an Int- which will return an Int".

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code reads:

A function `createAdder` that takes as an argument a `numberToAdd` of type `Integer` and *returns a function* that receives an `Integer` as an argument and returns an `Integer`. In this case, the function that is returned is the `adder` function that is created within the `createAdder`.